# Can't set the baud rate for my virtual terminal using the "stty" command

Tags: command-line

I am trying to set the baud rate for my virtual terminal using the `stty` command:

```
stty -F /dev/tty4 9600
```

But I am getting the following error:

```
stty: /dev/tty4: unable to perform all requested operations
```

Comment: Does it make sense to set the baud rate for virtual terminals? What are you trying to achieve here?

Comment: @muru I first thought that virtual terminals don't have a baud rate, but the command `stty -F /dev/tty4` actually returned a baud rate (in my case it is "speed 38400 baud").

Comment: That's probably a fake value returned by `agetty`. [`man agetty`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/en/man8/agetty.8.html) also says: "baud_rate .... This argument is optional and unnecessary for virtual terminals."

Comment: see https://superuser.com/questions/809582/what-is-the-significance-of-baud-rate-in-stty-settings-on-linux

Comment: @muru That's the answer, isn't it?

Comment: @dessert depends on what OP is actually trying to do here. If it was just experimentation, then yes.